# How can I display values from EditText user input?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a SharedPreferences that saves EditText input from one activity and displays the String value in another activity.

When I enter an input into the EditText fields and press (a button I created) "Save" (which commits the EditText to editor), the file is stored successfully. However, the display activity (which displays the stored String values in SharedPreferences) doesn't display the values. I am guessing it is because it is the onCreate, so the screen is "created" when it runs. How can I get it to update the EditText values when the user commits (presses save) immediately?

CustomStoreEditActivity - Just storing the user inputs (EditText entries):

```
    final Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (saveButton.isClickable()) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                        "customtime", 0);
                // prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
                final SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                EditText shopName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shopName);
                EditText open1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open1);
                EditText close1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close1);
                EditText open2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open2);
                EditText close2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close2);
                EditText open3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open3);
                EditText close3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close3);
                EditText open4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open4);
                EditText close4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close4);
                EditText open5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open5);
                EditText close5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close5);
                EditText open6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open6);
                EditText close6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close6);
                EditText open7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open7);
                EditText close7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close7);
                EditText comments = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comments);
                edit.putString("shopName", shopName.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Monday1", open1.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Monday2", close1.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Tuesday1", open2.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Tuesday2", close2.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Wednesday1", open3.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Wednesday2", close3.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Thursday1", open4.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Thursday2", close4.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Friday1", open5.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Friday2", close5.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Saturday1", open6.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Saturday2", close6.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Sunday1", open7.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("Sunday2", close7.getText().toString());
                edit.putString("comments", comments.getText().toString());
                edit.commit();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        CustomStoreActivity.class);
                myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(myIntent);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Opening Hours Saved!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    });

}
```

CustomStoreActivity - where I believe the problem lies:

```
    private void displayPreferences(){

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("customtime", 0);
    String shopName = prefs.getString("shopName", "Empty");
    String shopTime1 = prefs.getString("Monday1", " ");
    String shopTime2 = prefs.getString("Monday2",  " ");
    String shopComments = prefs.getString("comments", "");

    TextView displayPrefs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayPrefs);

    displayPrefs.setText(shopName + shopTime1 + shopTime2 + shopComments);

}
```

Thank you for your ample time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of what you're looking for is to put your CustomStoreActivity code in `onResume` instead of `onCreate`.  Whatever code you move into `onResume` will occur whenever the `CustomStoreActivity` is brought to the front (including when it is first created).

Another alternative, assuming that `CustomStoreActivity` is used to launch the `Activity` that contains the `EditText`s, is to use `startActivityForResult` and pass the data back in the result `Intent` instead of using the `SharedPreferences`.  [Here](http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Android-Activity-startActivityForResult-387002) is a simple example (though note that the `setResult` call in this example is passed `null` where you would want to pass in an `Intent`, as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) in the Android docs).

It also seems like  you're trying to use your second `Activity` like a dialog box with editable fields.  If that's the case, yet another alternative is to actually use a variant of the `Dialog` class within your `CustomStoreActivity` class instead of creating another `Activity` to act like one.  See the Android doc for [dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Comment: That worked, thank you very much Jon. I was unaware I could re-call OnResume() from another MapActivity. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome; though, you shouldn't ever have to manually invoke `onResume`.  I was assuming that you were viewing the `CustomStoreActivity` to start, and then launching the editor `Activity`, in which case it should be done automatically by the Android framework when you close the `Activity` in the foreground (the one you're using to update the text fields).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand your question but are you trying to update the TextView of a different Activity from the one you are in? In which case I don't think this can be done and you should use Intents to pass the data to the activity