# How can I display a previous EditText user input, as well as a recent EditText user input?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a SharedPreferences that saves EditText input from one activity and displays the String value in another activity.

When I enter an input into the EditText fields and press (a button I created) "Save" (which commits the EditText to editor), the file is stored and displayed successfully.

However, I want it so that everytime the user adds another entry in the EditText, it displays underneath the previously added EditText input. Like a list. I understand that both are reading from the SharedPreferences file. How would I go about doing this?

CustomStoreEditActivity - Just storing the user inputs (EditText entries):

```
   final Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (saveButton.isClickable()) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                    "customtime", 0);
            // prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
            final SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            EditText shopName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shopName);
            EditText open1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open1);
            EditText close1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close1);
            EditText open2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open2);
            EditText close2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close2);
            EditText open3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open3);
            EditText close3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close3);
            EditText open4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open4);
            EditText close4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close4);
            EditText open5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open5);
            EditText close5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close5);
            EditText open6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open6);
            EditText close6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close6);
            EditText open7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.open7);
            EditText close7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.close7);
            EditText comments = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comments);
            edit.putString("shopName", shopName.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Monday1", open1.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Monday2", close1.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Tuesday1", open2.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Tuesday2", close2.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Wednesday1", open3.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Wednesday2", close3.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Thursday1", open4.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Thursday2", close4.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Friday1", open5.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Friday2", close5.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Saturday1", open6.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Saturday2", close6.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Sunday1", open7.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("Sunday2", close7.getText().toString());
            edit.putString("comments", comments.getText().toString());
            edit.commit();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    CustomStoreActivity.class);
            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(myIntent);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Opening Hours Saved!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
});

}
```

CustomStoreActivity - where I retrieve the data and display:

```
    public void  onResume() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("customtime", 0);
    String shopName = prefs.getString("shopName", "Empty");
    String shopTimeM1 = prefs.getString("Monday1", " ");
    String shopTimeM2 = prefs.getString("Monday2",  " ");
    String shopTimeT1 = prefs.getString("Monday1", " ");
    String shopTimeT2 = prefs.getString("Monday2",  " ");
    String shopTimeW1 = prefs.getString("Monday1", " ");
    String shopTimeW2 = prefs.getString("Monday2",  " ");
    String shopTimeTH1 = prefs.getString("Monday1", " ");
    String shopTimeTH2 = prefs.getString("Monday2",  " ");
    String shopTimeF1 = prefs.getString("Monday1", " ");
    String shopTimeF2 = prefs.getString("Monday2",  " ");
    String shopTimeS1 = prefs.getString("Monday1", " ");
    String shopTimeS2 = prefs.getString("Monday2",  " ");
    String shopTimeSU1 = prefs.getString("Monday1", " ");
    String shopTimeSU2 = prefs.getString("Monday2",  " ");
    String shopComments = prefs.getString("comments", "");

    TextView displayPrefs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayPrefs);

    displayPrefs.setText(
            "------------------------------------------------------------" +
            "\n\nSHOP NAME: " + shopName +
            "\n\nTIMINGS: " + "\n\n  Monday: " + shopTimeM1 + " - " + shopTimeM2  +
            "\n  Tuesday: " + shopTimeT1 + " - " + shopTimeT2 + "\n  Wednesday: "
            + shopTimeW1 + " - " + shopTimeW2 + "\n  Thursday: " + shopTimeTH1 
            + " - " + shopTimeTH2 + "\n  Friday: " + shopTimeF1 + " - " + shopTimeF2 + 
            "\n  Saturday: " + shopTimeS1 + " - " + shopTimeS2 + "\n  Sunday: " +
            shopTimeSU1 + " - " + shopTimeSU2 +
            "\n\nCOMMENTS: " + shopComments +
            "\n\n------------------------------------------------------------");
    super.onResume();
}
```

Thank you for your humble time.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve.  Do you want the new strings to appear in the `CustomStoreEditActivity` as the user types (as static text above the editable text), or in the `CustomStoreActivity`?

Comment: Hey mate, simply - User enters a "shop name" and presses save. This then displays in my CustomStoreActivity. User enters another "shop name" and presses save. I want this second save to be displayed at the bottom of the previous save. Like a list. So the user can scroll through their "shop names" that they have added WITHIN CustomStoreActivity. Hopefully that is clear. Thank you for replying swiftly Jon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are trying to build a list.  Pardon my initially nebulous answer but I promise it will eventually focus in on a point.

What I would recommend for the overall framework is this:

You have an `Activity` (presumably your `CustomStoreActivity`) which displays a list of saved `Store` objects.  `Store` will need to implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable` (preferably the former).

On this `Activity` there is a `New Store` button (if you are following Android design convention, this is likely as a "+" button in the Action Bar).

On pressing the `New Store` button, your `CustomStoreActivity` calls `startActivityForResult(CustomStoreEditActivity.class)`.

Your `CustomStoreActivity` implements `onActivityResult` as per the answer on the last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233751/how-can-i-display-values-from-edittext-user-input) you asked.  Here, you will get a result code and an `Intent` which contains `Extras` (to be retrieved by `intent.getExtras()`).

Your `CustomStoreEditActivity` takes user input, as above, and instead of writing it to `SharedPreferences` it uses the information to create a new `Store` object which contains all of the information, and uses `setResult(RESULT_OK,intent)` where `intent` is the `Intent` to which you have added the `Store` extra (as a `Parcelable`).

This means that when `CustomStoreEditActivity` calls `finish()` (which you will do instead of using an intent to re-launch your `CustomStoreActivity` because the `CustomStoreActivity` is already just behind it) you'll get your call to `onActivityResult` and can pull the `Store` object out of the `Extras` from the `Intent` you just passed back.

And now to the point:

You can use a `ListView` in your `CustomStoreActivity`, and use a `StoreAdapter` that extends `ArrayAdapter<Store>`, and for each item in the list of `Store`s adds a view to the list containing that `Store`'s name.  Then you'll just add your new `Store` object to the array you passed into your `StoreAdapter`, and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onActivityResult` and that should take care of it.

If ultimately you need to persist this data between application sessions, you should handle writing the `Store` objects to the `SharedPreferences` in the `onPause` method of `CustomStoreActivity` (it being the keeper of the list) rather than touching your shared preferences from every direction.  You can then read in the list again in `onCreate` should you need to.

I know it's a lot to parse through/digest, but it's a pretty standard mechanism for passing data between `Activity` constructs in Android and for persisting data.

Let me know if you have any questions on the implementation and I'll see what I can do!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer here: [Show a drop down list of recently entered text when clicks on an android edit box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499530/show-a-drop-down-list-of-recently-entered-text-when-clicks-on-an-android-edit-bo/15368045#15368045)

All you would really need to do is change the preference mode to public, not private.