# how can I save my spinner input?

Tags: android, eclipse, save, spinner

I've create one spinner and I want to save all of spinner input when i close my application. How can I do? I think shared preferences can help me but i don't know how can use it!
This is my code:

```
 private Spinner spinner;
      private EditText Text;
      private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
      private Button addButton;

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        final List<String> planets = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.clienti_arrays)));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planets);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_new);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
            addNewSpinnerItem();
            Collections.sort(planets);

          }
        });
      }

      protected void addNewSpinnerItem()
      {
        String textHolder = "" + Text.getText().toString();
        adapter.add(textHolder);

      }

      public int compare(String s1, String s2) { return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase()); 

      }

    }
```

Thanks a lot for your help..

Answer (score 2):

Override `onPause()` of Activity to save selected values in `Shared Preferences` when your application going to close as:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    // get Spinner Slected text here
  String selectedtext = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

   //Create SharedPreferences to store selected value

    SharedPreferences spinnerPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("spinnerPrefs", 
                                                           MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = spinnerPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString("spinner_selectedtext", selectedtext);
    prefsEditor.commit();

    super.onPause();

}
```

and to retrieve values saved in `SharedPreferences` :

```
 SharedPreferences spinnerPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("spinnerPrefs",
                                                           MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 String selectedtext = spinnerPrefs.getString("spinner_selectedtext", 
                                                             "nothing_selected");
```

Comment: it don't function..make me one error! in the       String selectedtext = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: @Ormet : what error you are getting if you share this error with me then we will resolve it quickly

Comment: it make me this error: at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146) in SharedPreferences spinnerPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("spinnerPrefs",
                  MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

Comment: @Ormet : depend on you where you are using this code make sure you are using right context for accessing SharedPreferences use `Your_Current_Activity.this. getSharedPreferences` instead of `this.getSharedPreferences..`

Comment: The problem is the same! if I don't instert this code " SharedPreferences spinnerPrefs = MyAndroidAppActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("spinnerPrefs",
      MODE_PRIVATE);
    String selectedtext = spinnerPrefs.getString("spinner_selectedtext", 
                    "nothing_selected");
" function normally but don't save nothing..when I insert it breaks..why??where I must insert it?

Comment: @Ormet : ok post your latest code then i will see where you are using it now . you known this is just context issue or nothing

Comment: after compare (String s1....) i've instert  @Override
public void onPause()
{
    
  String selectedtext = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    SharedPreferences spinnerPrefs =... and SharedPreferences spinnerPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("spinnerPrefs",
                                                           MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 String selectedtext = spinnerPrefs.getString("spinner_selectedtext", "nothing_selected");

Comment: @Ormet : if you edit your post with latest code and crashing log then this is very helpful to solve your issue very shortly

Comment: @Ormet : give me right link im not able to download or view it

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ktl89da55pr0g5g/log.txt and https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7vkb6ymc47dakb/src.txt ..sorry

Comment: @Ormet : if you have no problem then give me a link of full code because then i will try it to run on my end .if it's non offical

Comment: @Ormet : what is MyAndroidAppActivity.java:87 line in MyAndroidAppActivity Activity?

Comment: @Ormet : sorry i forget to post you . just use this class http://pastebin.com/asdGnvjc

Comment: @Ormet : don't forget to upvote or accept it answer.Thanks so much . but you response time is very low

Comment: in my emulator don't function (when i exit and restart the application haven't save any spinner). when i come home i will try with my phone..

Comment: @Ormet : check log i have tested in my end it's working but just add new values to spinner when activity resume or restart

Comment: i've tried also with my phone but when i exit from application or make a screen rotation it loose all of my spinner.. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21473/discussion-between--k-and-ormet)

Comment: @send me your code to me and explain in detail what you want for better response

Comment: i can't write in chat, why? my newest file is https://www.dropbox.com/s/487vieuucx9zgsw/salva.zip

Comment: @Ormet : what can i do in this new files

Comment: i've send you my code as you wanted to explain my problem..i copied your modify but i've the same problem

Comment: @Ormet : dear i'm saying you explain me clearly what you want

Comment: in my emulator and also in my phone when i exit and restart the application haven't save any spinner..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21594/discussion-between-ormet-and--k)

Comment: hi @prosper K, i'm here..sorry but in chat I can't write anything..I don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

I detail how to do this in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499530/show-a-drop-down-list-of-recently-entered-text-when-clicks-on-an-android-edit-bo/15368045#15368045). Each time you enter an item in the edittext, it saves it to the spinner which holds the x last items you enter. The memory stays until you uninstall the app or manually clear the data.